# Graphql array response to ReasonReact

Tags: ocaml, graphql, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

Trying to figure working with data in reason. I have this graphql query returning data a logging it. Question is how do I access the data in the following component.

```
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("Home");

let make = (_) => {
  ...component,
  render: (_self) =>
    <View>
      <Hello message="Hello from home component" />
      <FetchEpisodes>
        (
          (response) => {
            Js.log(response);
            /* let episodeItems =
               Array.of_list(
                 List.map(
                   (response) =>
                     <Episode
                       key=response##data##allEpisodes##id
                       episode=response##data##allEpisodes##episode
                     />,
                 )
               ); */
            <div> <h1> (ReasonReact.stringToElement("Episodes!")) </h1> </div>
            /* (ReasonReact.arrayToElement(episodeItems)) */
          }
        )
      </FetchEpisodes>
    </View>
};
```

This is the query response:
[image]

coming from JS i keep wanting to log allEpisodes with some like response.data...which doesn't work here, obviously

Gists to components: [episode component](https://gist.github.com/idkjs/fb541ca929950879d4000e37fd26eadf), [home.re component](https://gist.github.com/idkjs/1e463f1d6de3af3c4e2af2e507413954)

If i uncomment and run, it produces the following error:

```

```
FAILED: src/pages/home.mlast
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bs-platform/bin/bsc.exe -pp "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bs-platform/bin/refmt3.exe --print binary" -ppx '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bs-platform/bin/reactjs_jsx_ppx_2.exe'   -w -30-40+6+7+27+32..39+44+45+101 -nostdlib -I '/Users/shingdev/code/REASON/with-reason-apollo-master/node_modules/bs-platform/lib/ocaml' -bs-super-errors -no-alias-deps -color always -c -o src/pages/home.mlast -bs-syntax-only -bs-binary-ast -impl /Users/shingdev/code/REASON/with-reason-apollo-master/src/pages/home.re
File "/Users/shingdev/code/REASON/with-reason-apollo-master/src/pages/home.re", line 53, characters 17-18:
Error: 2806: <UNKNOWN SYNTAX ERROR>

  We've found a bug for you!
  /Users/shingdev/code/REASON/with-reason-apollo-master/src/pages/home.re

  There's been an error running Reason's refmt parser on a file.
  This was the command:

  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bs-platform/bin/refmt3.exe --print binary '/Users/shingdev/code/REASON/with-reason-apollo-master/src/pages/home.re' > /var/folders/qx/xhwh5zfj7z36_bjh5187svx00000gn/T/ocamlpp530e68
```

```

I'm not understanding how to process the response object when an array is returned. Thank you.

UPDATE per @glennsl's suggestion:

````
```
let make = (_) => {
  ...component,
  render: (_self) =>
    <View>
      <Hello message="Hello from home component" />
      /* <Greeting name="Tony" /> */
      <FetchEpisodes>
        (
          (response) => {
            let episodeItems =
              response##data##allEpisodes
              |> Array.map((episode) => <Episode key=episode##id title=episode##title />);
            <div> <h1> (ReasonReact.stringToElement("Episodes!")) </h1> </div>(
              ReasonReact.arrayToElement(episodeItems)
            )
          }
        )
      </FetchEpisodes>
    </View>
};
```
````

This produces the following error:

[image]

I'm figuring its coming because the types arent being passed to episode.re

````
```
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("Episode");

let make = (~style=?, ~episode, _children) => {
  ...component,
  render: (_self) => <View ?style> <h1> (ReasonReact.stringToElement(episode)) </h1> </View>
};
```
````

Am I supposed to pass list(episode) somewhere?

UPDATE 2: This code works as far as JSX thanks to @glennsl

````
```

let make = (_) => {
  ...component,
  render: (_self) =>
    <View>
      <Hello message="Hello from home component" />
      /* <Greeting name="Tony" /> */
      <FetchEpisodes>
        (
          (response) => {
            let episodeItems =
              response##data##allEpisodes
              |> Array.map((episode) => <Episode key=episode##id episode=episode##episode />);
            <div>
              <h1> (ReasonReact.stringToElement("Episodes!")) </h1>
              (ReasonReact.arrayToElement(episodeItems))
            </div>
          }
        )
      </FetchEpisodes>
    </View>
};
```
````

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me why this obviously doesn't work. Do you get an error, or does it just not work as expected?

Comment: @glennsl Obviously, meaning something is wrong hence, Im asking a question. My bad. I updated with the error it produces. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Ok, I thought you had problems even just logging the response. The syntax error is just because there's a dangling `,` in `List.map`, but you're also missing the second argument and have plenty of type errors in there too. Let me cook up a suggestion in an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I think:

```
type episode = {. "id": string, "title": string, "episode": string};
type data = {. "allEpisodes": array(episode)};

...

(response) => {
  let episodeItems =
    response##data##allEpisodes
    |> Array.map((episode) =>
       <Episode key=episode##id
                episode=episode##episode />);

  <div>
    <h1> (ReasonReact.stringToElement("Episodes!")) </h1>
    (ReasonReact.arrayToElement(episodeItems))
  </div>
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't, or if any of this confuses you I'll happily explain.

Edit: You've also typed `data##allEpisodes` as `list(episode)` when it's actually `array(episode)`. Updated the code block above. A `list` is not the same as an `array`, the former is a linked list type while the latter is equivalent to a JavaScript array.

Edit 2: Fixed JSX

Comment: so if this is episode.re```let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("Episode");

let make = (~style=?, ~episode, _children) => {
  ...component,
  render: (_self) => <View ?style> <h1> (ReasonReact.stringToElement(episode)) </h1> </View>
};``` I would have to pass the title type to make, correct?

Comment: Title type? If you want to print the title with that Episode component, you'd have to pass it the value of the title property: `<Episode key=episode##id episode=episode##title />`

Comment: I'm still producing errors. This is the demo repo. https://github.com/idkjs/reason-arrays-demo. Also, what is this concept named so I can look it up in the docs?

Comment: Seems to not like the way the data type is defined or I'm not telling it how to read it the correct way. Error: ```This is:
    (array(Js.t(({.. id : string, title : string } as 'a)))) =>
    array(ReasonReact.reactElement)
  But somewhere wanted:
    (list(episode)) => 'b

  The incompatible parts:
    array(Js.t('a))
    vs
    at <anonymous>```

Comment: Ah, your data is incorrectly typed, see the edited answer. Also, which concept are you referring to?

Comment: Ok. So. The following has some kind of formatting error I cant work out.```<FetchEpisodes>
        (
          (response) => {
            Js.log(response);
            let episodeItems =
              response##data##allEpisodes
              |> Array.map((episode) => <Episode key=episode##id episode=episode##episode />);
            <div> <h1> (ReasonReact.stringToElement("Episodes!")) </h1> </div>(
              ReasonReact.arrayToElement(episodeItems)
            )
          }
        )
      </FetchEpisodes>```

Comment: This is the error: Error: This expression has type ReasonReact.reactElement
  It seems to have been called like a function? Maybe you forgot    at <anonymous>here?

Comment: Hmm, yea that's a confusing error that means you're trying to return more than a single `reactElement`. I've updated the answer with the fixed JSX.

Comment: Im thinking that the Episode.re module already returns a ReactElement and i should be able to call episodeItems directly as a return value. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can return `ReasonReact.arrayToElement(episodeItems)` directly, yes. It might be a good idea to DM me on Discord if you have more follow-up questions. This comment thread's getting a bit long :)

Comment: You should also keep SO questions to a single specific problem, and not update them when you encounter new problems. SO intends to be a knowledge base, not a general debugging/problem-fixing service. Discord is a better forum for that kind of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
response##data##allEpisodes
|> Array.map((episode) =>
```

This won't work because `response##data##allEpisodes` returns undefined. I believe it's because in [reason-apollo]: https://github.com/Gregoirevda/reason-apollo/blob/master/src/ReasonApollo.re#L29  `data` is typed as a string.

Comment: Sorry for adding an answer. I don't have enough points to comment.

Comment: Got the same errror. Strange because previously, before had jsx fixed, it was coming back and logging to console. Now it just doesn't wait for it. How does one handle async in reason?